# Does `Application.StatusBar` work in office 2011?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, statusbar, excel-2011

I wrote this little macro on my mac using office 2011.  I don't see any status bar.  Anyone know why this is not working?

```
Sub testStastusBar()

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Now processing...."

    Dim n As Integer
    For n = 1 To 10
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Debug.Print n
    Next n

    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I have not used macros all that much. Do you just write them in Excel or do you have to use Visual Basic .NET? Seems like a simple question but I mostly use Java and C++ so the macros I have not used all that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it work with Excel 2011, add `DoEvents` after updating the statusbar.

```
Sub testStastusBar()

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Now processing...."

    DoEvents '<~~ Add This

    Dim n As Integer
    For n = 1 To 10
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Debug.Print n
    Next n

    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```